# Error: error code 1 for command :cmd with args: /s,/c

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to cordova while making android build it is giving error. following is the error.

[image: error image 1]

[image: my enviroment variable details:]

Comment: You gotta change the android sdk version to the compatible jdk version. What android sdk version are you using?

Comment: android-17,22,23,24 these are the sdks i have installed

Comment: What version of cordova are you using?